# FileZilla public key not working (Successfully loaded 0 key pairs from file)

Tags: ssh, putty, sftp, filezilla, public-key

I currently have troubles logging in with a public key using FileZilla.
Neither the root user, not an other user accept the key.

Now the strange thing is when using putty it is working without any troubles.

I do not have the slightest idea what the problem might be.

Things I checked:

- Connection to the server:
  The server does receive the authentication attempt
- The key is located in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- The file permissions are correct *(`700` for `~/.ssh` and `600` for `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`)*
- Using the same key with PuTTY. This is **working**!
- Password login over SFTP is working as well
- Trying a new key: Not working as well *(PuTTY is accepting it without problems)*

### Logs:

PuTTY:

```
Event Log: Writing new session log (SSH packets mode) to file: PuTTY.log
Event Log: Looking up host "x.x.x.x"
Event Log: Connecting to x.x.x.x port 22
Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2
Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.63_(file_config_0.6.1)
Event Log: Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Event Log: Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Event Log: Host key fingerprint is:
Event Log: ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
Event Log: Reading private key file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\PBS - Verknüpfungen\root.key.ppk"
Event Log: Offered public key
Event Log: Offer of public key accepted
Event Log: Sent public key signature
Event Log: Access granted
Event Log: Opening session as main channel
Event Log: Opened main channel
Event Log: Requesting X11 forwarding
Event Log: X11 forwarding enabled
Event Log: Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
Event Log: Started a shell/command
```

FileZilla:

```
Status: Connecting to x.x.x.x...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=2
Command:    keyfile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\PBS - Verknüpfungen\root.key.ppk"
Command:    open "root@x.x.x.x" 22
Trace:  Looking up host "x.x.x.x"
Trace:  Connecting to x.x.x.x port 22
Trace:  We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Local:_Mar_29_2015_12:25:15
Trace:  Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
Trace:  We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
Trace:  Using SSH protocol version 2
Trace:  Doing ECDH key exchange with hash SHA-256
Trace:  Host key fingerprint is:
Trace:  ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Trace:  Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Trace:  Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Trace:  Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Trace:  Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
Trace:  Successfully loaded 0 key pairs from file
Error:  Connection attempt interrupted by user
```

*(The last message is caused by me pressing cancel after being asked for the password)*

Comment: Can you include PuTTY event log as well as corresponding FileZilla log?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Like this?

Comment: No, I mean FileZilla **log file** (*Edit > Settings > Logging*). Few more lines from PuTTY event log too please.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Like this? *(If not I don't know what you want)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably the umlaut in the path. The interface between FileZilla and the internal psftp process is not Unicode-enabled.

When I tried a path with diacritics, psftp didn't load the key either:

```
Trace:  Successfully loaded 0 key pairs from file
```

When I removed the diacritics, it worked:

```
Trace:  Successfully loaded 1 key pair from file
Trace:  Offered public key from "C:\path\key.ppk"
```

Comment: That was the issue. Thnk you